# How to restrict findTransformEcc to a partial affine transform with scale but without shear?

Tags: opencv, emgucv, affinetransform, stereoscopy

I built a stereoscopic camera mobile app which performs automatic alignment using findTransformEcc and the app is working pretty well with it. I know I should probably be using rectifyStereoUncalibrated preceded by keypoints and descriptors etc. etc. but I get bad results from that despite many different approaches attempted and I'm super frustrated. So instead, I'm sticking with findTransformEcc (at least for now). At the moment I'm using MotionType.Euclidean (restricted to translations and rotations) but I would like to change that.

So far, the app has worked by having the user take one picture and move to the side to capture the next (chacha method). But now I'm adding the ability to have two phones capture simultaneously. The problem is that the focal length and sensor size (angular field of view) may be different between the two cameras, so in order to align the two pictures I need to allow scaling/zooming. However, if I want to do that with findTransformEcc I can only step up from Euclidean to Affine, it seems like I can't go between. That is, it seems I cannot allow scaling without also allowing shearing, and I don't want shearing.

As another way to explain this, I'd like to get the type of transform that you can get from estimateRigidTranform(array,array,FALSE) (partial affine) but rather than using keypoints as that function does, I want to use findTransformEcc because from my experimentation it just seems to be more reliable.

(https://github.com/KRA2008/crosscam/blob/develop/AutoAlignment/OpenCV.cs is the auto-alignment code if that helps at all)

Comment: Is it not a case of calling `CvInvoke.FindTransformECC` with `MotionCriteria` == `MotionType.Affine` in order to return the Affine transform as `CvInvoke.EstimateRigidTransform` does? http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.4.1/document/html/f2b21ec7-23b4-f0f9-9125-e5c2185f5d4a.htm

Comment: Also, I'm not certain, but I'm of the understanding that you could simply omit the shear values at [0,1] and [1,0], scalars being at [0,0] and [1,1]?

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood What I glean from the documentation (and my experimentation) is that using `MotionCriteria == MotionType.Affine` with `CvInvoke.FindTransformECC` is analogous to `CvInvoke.EstimateRigidTransform` with a `true` for the FullAffine argument. The problem is I don't see what the analog would be for a `false`. It's something "in between" `MotionCriteria == MotionType.Affine` and ``MotionCriteria == MotionType.Euclidean`

Comment: Here's the doc for `EstimateRigidTransform` which explains the `true/false` for full affine: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#estimaterigidtransform

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood Reply to your second comment: it does sound like that might be what I have to resort to but I don't like it. It just seems like it's going to result in some less-than-ideal results. My understanding is that as the algorithm does its estimating, it's tweaking parameters little by little and tuning the transform matrix to get the best match, but if at the end I just hack off some components it's not going to be optimized to the same location as if the algorithm had been restricted to partial affine the whole time.

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood Actually, after some more thought, I don't even know how I would remove just the skew portion even if I wanted to. In an affine transform isn't it mixed in with the rotation and scale components? https://nghiaho.com/?p=2208

Comment: I understand your concerns for the derivation of the result but I'm afraid I don't know if they are justified. In either case, with regards to discarding components, looking again, I believe you're right (I was wrong) that the skew components are compounded with rotation. (https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2c/2D_affine_transformation_matrix.svg/250px-2D_affine_transformation_matrix.svg.png). Why is it that you do not want to permit shear? I'm sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood I don't want to permit shear because it's just an unnatural transformation - it isn't the type of error that would be introduced while doing a stereo capture so it isn't the kind of correction that will produce realistic results. I'm still looking at whether there's an algebraic way to remove the skew. I do appreciate you engaging with me and making me think, even if you don't have an instant easy answer. Thanks.

Comment: A final parting thought; might it be the case, given your explanation here, that although the affine transform is "full", that it's skew component is negligible? That said, I assume you've tried already. Don't forget of course that the source code for both methods is available to you, if you are mathematically competent (I am not), perhaps a solution can be derived. Good luck and post your answer on success, I''ll be interested to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Fourier-Mellin transform based approach: https://github.com/Smorodov/LogPolarFFTTemplateMatcher

It will give you offset, scale and rotation parameters, nothing more.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your contribution is more suitable for a comment rather than being an answer.

Comment: thank you so much! i haven't tried it yet but this sounds extremely promising and may be exactly what i needed. this is one of those times when i'm on stack overflow saying "i'm trying to do X using Y but it won't Z" and you come along and say "do X with W instead, then your trouble with Y doesn't matter", which is great! i'll come back and mark it as the answer if it works.

Comment: my app is built in Xamarin and while i'm not sure how to actually consume the project you linked to, with having done more research i am now sure it is the correct answer to what i'm trying to do. marked as answered.